# Почему приложение Qt Quick нормально запускается в обычном режиме, но не запускается в режиме отладки?

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-emulator, remote-debugging

Я пытаюсь запустить приложение Qt Quick в режиме отладки из QtCreator-a, сборка под андроид, андроид работает на эмуляторе. Сборка и выгрузка приложения на устройство проходят без ошибок, затем начинаются странности: запускаются 2 отладчика(или происходит две попытки запуска отладчика, не понятно), как показано на скриншоте:
[image: Два отладчика]

Затем один запуск завершается, а второй зависает, через 20 секунд IDE предлагает остановить отладчик, как показано на скриношоте:

[image: Остановка отладчика]

Кнопка Stop Debugging закрывает модальное окно, но отладчик не останавливает. Приложение на андроид ожидает присоединения отладчика с момента выгрузки, но он не присоединяется, приложение можно только закрыть при  помощи кнопки принудительного выхода. При закрытии приложения таким способом в IDE возникает  ошибка присоединения к отладчику:

[image: Ошибка присоединения]

Информация о системе:

- ОС: Windows 11
- Qt Creator 6.0.1 64bit
- Эмулируемое устройство: Emulator for Galaxy Nexus x86 Android 8.1 SDK(27)

Что пробовал: переустановку QtCreator; переустановку Android Studio; изменение версиq SDK, NDK, JDK; менял архитектуру эмулируемого устройства; менял целевую платформу сборки;

Comment: Дык может дать ему немного времени? Было у меня как-то приложение, которое под gdb стартовало несколько минут.

Comment: За 15 минут не запустилось.

Comment: `This could mean it is stuck in an enless loop...` - проверьте на наличие бесконечных циклов, или зацикливаний

Comment: Это происходит даже в только-что созданном проекте, так что зацикливаниям взяться не откуда.